# How to pass a value as url in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I had specified like,

```
@foreach (int ans in Model.UnAnsweredList)
{
    <a href="/Dashboard/GoToAnswer?@ans/">@ans</a>
}
```

and its get method given as,

```
 public ActionResult GoToAnswer(int? number)
```

Even though the ans is int type, the value does not pass to the method.
kindly tell me what  should i do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use query string you need to specify the `name` of the parameter like `name=value` (as it's a key-value dictionary, so you cannot omit the parameter's name).

You need to change you link to this:

```
@foreach (int ans in Model.UnAnsweredList)
{
    <a href="/Dashboard/GoToAnswer?number=@ans">@ans</a>
}
```

But in fact, you should better use an `Html.ActionLink` method as your custom routes will be applied:

```
@foreach (int ans in Model.UnAnsweredList)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(ans, "GotToAnswer", "DashBoard", new {number=ans})
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `number` is not in your routing, you should name the parameter:

```
<a href="/Dashboard/GoToAnswer?number=@ans/">@ans</a>
```

If it were in your routing, you wouldn't use the query string:

```
<a href="/Dashboard/GoToAnswer/@ans/">@ans</a>
```

Comment: Values coming after '?' are not treated as route parameters, so even if it were there it would be ingored

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I know, if it were in routing the URL would be `/Dashboard/GoToAnswer/@ans`, better printed using an `@Html.ActionLink()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using HTML helpers.

```
@HTML.ActionLink(ans, "GoToAnswer", "ControllerName", new { number = ans })
```